# Example: Tablesorter Output widget difference between download and popup special characters

Tags: csv, output, tablesorter

I am using the output widget of tablesorter to get my table as csv (for excel). The table has no problems with special chars. If I export the data as output its all fine. If I use download option special characters like `&` are shown as `&amp;` (seen in Notepad++) so Excel decides to separate it as there is a `;`

Any help?
UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/6503/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example (you can [modify this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/2617/))? Is the original markup in the table using html codes like `&amp;`?

Comment: Hi Mottie, thanks for the reply. I added an example: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/6503/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see what you're saying, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I ended up adding a new callback function `output_formatContent`*. Use it as follows ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/6529/)):

```
output_formatContent: function (config, widgetOptions, data) {
  // data.isHeader (boolean) = true if processing a header cell
  // data.$cell = jQuery object of the cell currently being processed
  // data.content = processed cell content
  //    (spaces trimmed, quotes added/replaced, etc)
  // **********
  // use data.$cell.html() to get the original cell content
  return data.content.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
}
```

if you want to replace all HTML codes, then check out Mathias Bynens [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he#hedecodehtml-options) which would work as follows:

```
output_formatContent : function( c, wo, data ) {
  // replace all HTML shortcut codes
  // (e.g. 'foo &copy; bar &ne; baz &#x1D306; qux' becomes 'foo © bar ≠ baz  qux' )
  return he.decode( data.content );
}
```

* Note: the new output widget callback is currently only available in the [master branch of the tablesorter repository](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-output.js). It will be included in the next update.

Comment: I use the output_formatContent to replace the CSS hyphens `&shy;`